# Xamarin Forms Shell Flyout: How can I remove the gap between FlyoutHeader and the first FlyoutItem?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

There is a gap in Shell's Flyout as seen in the picture below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H70mx.png)
(*Header background is black and item background is yellow. The white in between is what I'm trying to remove.*)

I have tested this in a blank new project (where I've also taken this screenshot) so I'm pretty sure it's not my code's doing. I tried setting margins and/or paddings to most of the elements in the AppShell.

If it helps, when I pull the items down, the blueish "[you-are-trying-to-pull-a-scrollable-list-past-its-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icWOf.png)" graphic is right below the header, so that makes me think that the gap is part of the Flyout's internal item list.

Any ideas on how I could remove the gap?

Comment: According to the official document, in Android, the white in between exists. And in IOS, there is no white in between. You can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can see that on the screenshot now. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document, in Android, the white in between exists. And in IOS, there is no white in between.

In the picture below, we can see the difference between the IOS and Android.
[image]

For more details, you can refer to: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create